# Can we use appositives before the subject?

Tags: usage, appositives

1. Good vocabulary, knowledge of grammar, sense of style--all are basic writing skills.
2. Basic writing skills--good vocabulary, knowledge of grammar, sense of style-- can be learned by almost everyone.

In (2) the series of appositives are "good vocabulary, knowledge of grammar, sense of style". So by definition "The appositive is a noun or noun phrase that modifies another noun" so it means appositive comes after the subject right?

But my doubt is can we use appostives before a subject like in (1) and in (1) which is the subject(i.e noun) that
modifies the noun phrases "Good vocabulary, knowledge of grammar, sense of style" ?

Comment: [*An **appositive** is a noun or noun phrase that **renames another noun** right beside it.*](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/appositive.htm) Your examples aren't "appositives" - they're just ***lists*** (of three nouns identifying thee *different* basic writing skills). An example of a true appositive would be, for example, *The OP here, **a new visitor to ELL**, was mistaken about the meaning of the word "appositive".*

Comment: Sorry, I am not new to ELL and I have already mentioned the definition of appositive in question itself. When I was reading about Sentence Patterns I  got doubt on this. So in Pattern 6:  An Introductory Series of Appositive. Example:The depressed, the stressed, the lonely, the fearful—all have trouble coping with problems. Pattern 7: An Internal Series of Appositives or Modifiers.  Example: Basic writing skills--good vocabulary, knowledge of grammar, sense of style--can be learned by almost everyone. So could you please answer to my question now?

Comment: It was only an *example* usage. Obviously I drew a mistaken conclusion from the fact that you only have 1 rep point, but I see now that you've been a member here for 11 days. Having said that, I can't help thinking it's rather odd that you asked three earlier questions over a week ago, and no-one here has upvoted any of the questions or answers. So I'm off to have a look at them now.

Comment: Any answers???!

Comment: Consider *The brothers **, (Tom, Dick, and Harry),** all died.* I'd say that *in its entirety*, the parenthetical element there is indeed an "appositive", but each of the three names is simply an *item in a list*. But your first example is equivalent to recasting my example as *Tom, Dick, and Harry are [all] brothers [who have died]*, and I just don't think "appositive" is a relevant term in such constructions. But I'm not a big fan of nitpicking over details of grammatical terminology, so I'll leave it to someone who's more interested in that sort of thing to provide a formal "Answer" here.

Comment: If no one knows the exact answer for this question then why the author used this topic in his book? (The Art of Styling
Sentences: 20 Patterns). Please could you look at that book once or browse it and answer me.

Comment: As I said, I personally don't care much about such fine details of terminology. I never needed to know them myself to get my degree in English, and it's not obvious to me how knowing the *exact* limits of what could be called an "appositive" usage would help anyone *learn* English. It seems to me that in [*My Aunt, **Mary Elizabeth Trosper,** was born in Pineville*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22my+aunt+mary+Elizabeth+Trosper%22) the highlighted element is definitely an appositive. I doubt you could say that about *My Aunt **Mary** died yesterday*, but honestly - who cares?

Comment: Actually I am not a native speaker and I learned English as my second language so I just curious about usage of this language. When I searched about sentence patterns I found this kind of sentences. After reading that patterns, really, I am totally confused about patterns in English.

Comment: Though you people are a native speaker, you people don't know how and why they (The Art of
Styling Sentences) used these type of patterns in this book.

Comment: I put the same question in English Language Learners Stack Exchange, English language and stack exchange, and English language and Linguistics. In these 3, all were saying those are NOT appositives. If they are not appositives then why that author written those type of sentences?? So here which is right answer? the author is or the one who answers here are right?? Which one is right to believe??

Comment: I'd be happy to pronounce on whether any given usage is "idiomatically acceptable" or not, or to discuss potential implications/entailments, but I'm not qualified to say which "marginal" usages could validly be called "appositive" - nor do I understand why this matters to you. I can tell you for certain that your first example *isn't* appositive - and as for the second one, it really depends on whether you consider the parenthetical element to be a ***full restatement*** of "basic writing skills", or a ***list of three examples*** (implying there are ***other*** skills in that category).

Comment: For patterns, think of a quilt: whatever repeats is a pattern.

Comment: Again: parenthetical words are not appositives. And three items at the start of a sentence are not appositives either. appositives don't modify anything; they **restate** something. They can be phrases but they are usually nouns.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.**

Appositives most commonly appear after the noun or pronoun they rename, as in these examples from Pattern 7 from [The Art of Styling Sentences](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0096DJZB2) (I have **boldfaced** the appositives and italicized the noun they rename):

> He learned the necessary *qualities* for political life -- **guile**, **ruthlessness**, and **garrulity** -- by carefully studying his father's life.
>
> My favorite red *wines* -- **Zinfandel**, **Cabernet Sauvignon**, **Pinot Noir** -- blend well in making California rosé wines.
>
> The basic writing *skills* (**good vocabulary**, **knowledge of grammar**, **sense of style**) can be learned by almost everyone.

However, as shown in these examples from Pattern 6 of the same book, appositives can also appear before their associated noun or pronoun. In these cases, the appositive usually starts the sentence:

> **The depressed**, **the stressed**, **the lonely**, **the fearful** -- *all* have trouble coping with problems.

Here, "the depressed", "the stressed", "the lonely", and "the fearful" are appositives renaming the subject "all".

> **Gluttony**, **lust**, **envy** -- *which* is the worst sin?

"Which" is the pronoun being renamed here.

The link to [Grammar Bytes!](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/appositive.htm) given by FumbleFingers in the comments includes another example:

> When the appositive begins the sentence, it looks like this:
>
> > **A hot-tempered tennis player**, *Robbie* charged the umpire and tried to crack the poor man's skull with a racket.

Comment: parentheticals are not appositives. And gluttony, lust, envy are not appositives either. They do not rename anything. They are three different things.

Answer (score 0):

Your examples are both good, although I wouldn't say that an appositive "modifies" anything.  It's simply a rephrasing.

Answer (score 0):

1) Good vocabulary, knowledge of grammar, sense of style--all are basic writing skills.

There is no appositive in the sentence above. There are three noun phrases, all different. There are three different things, not the same things.

2) Basic writing skills--good vocabulary, knowledge of grammar, sense of style-- can be learned by almost everyone.

In the sentence above, there is no apposition.

Here are FumbleFingers' examples:

1) Tom, Dick and Harry, the brothers [brothers renames Tom, Dick and Harry]

2) The OP here, a new visitor to ELL [a new visitor renames the OP]

3) My Aunt, Mary Elizabeth Trosper [the name renames My Aunt]

An appositive has to RENAME a thing, but not be a completely different thing. An appositive is NOT three items starting a sentence.

Bananas, apples and oranges were on the table. [no appositive]

Bananas, an edible fruit, were on the table. edible fruit renames bananas]

Appositions can be used anywhere in a sentence to rename an existing person or thing.

- The orange man, aka the US president, is unfit for office.
- That scum ball doctor, a true pervert, molested those girls.
- A large dog, man's best friend, can be a lot of work.
- Any cat, a furry feline creature, is great for petting.

**Appositives always come AFTER the noun they accompany** and rename them or restate them. They are often at the beginning of sentences, but not always.

John was coming down the driveway in red RAM truck, a very heavy car.

Answer (score 0):

Virginia Tufte in her book *Artful Sentences*, talks about "inverted" and "initial" appositives, as in "A lonely boy, Coleridge retreated into books...and fed his mind with adventures so wild and fancies so morbid that he often feared the coming of the night" so I'm not convinced that appositives "Always come AFTER the noun."

What she doesn't say, but I think she should--and the examples provided above from *The Art of Styling Sentences* have further emboldened me to think so-- is that these inverted appositives have to be at the beginning of sentences and the noun that follows the appositive has to be the subject of the sentence. Otherwise, I have no answer for the student who might say to me, Well why isn't Coleridge in apposition to "A lonely boy" instead of the other way around?

I'm curious, has anyone else heard the term Tufte uses,"inverted appositive"?

Comment: embolden, not enbolden

Comment: Yegads, I actually think I have always thought it was spelled "enbolden." In other words, I can't even pretend it was a typo. Thank you, editing now.